# Drawing straight lines for not aligned classes in tikzuml

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw, tikz-uml

I've been playing with all the options of the `tikz-uml` package to get a straight line for two classes that are not aligned

```
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}


\begin{document}\errorcontextlines=9

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}

            \umlclass[]{ApplicationController}
            {
                
            }
            {
                
            }

            \umlclass[below right=2cm and -1cm of ApplicationController]{RelayHandler}{}
            {
                
            }

            \umluniassoc[]{ApplicationController}{RelayHandler}
            

        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

What I need is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With the calc library, I place an auxiliary point `(aux)`at the center of the `south east` edge of the "Application controller" box and the `north west` edge of the "RelayHandler" node.
Then using the syntax, `|-` I place the arrow.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc}
\tikzset{> = {Straight Barb[length=4pt,width=3.4pt]}}

\begin{document}\errorcontextlines=9

%\begin{figure}[H]
%    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}

            \umlclass[]{ApplicationController}
            {
                
            }
            {
                
            }

            \umlclass[below right=2cm and -1cm of ApplicationController]{RelayHandler}{}
            {
                
            }

%            \umluniassoc[]{ApplicationController}{RelayHandler}
            \coordinate (aux) at ($(ApplicationController.south east)!.5!(RelayHandler.north west)$);
            \draw[->](ApplicationController.south-|aux)--(aux|-RelayHandler.north);

        \end{tikzpicture}
%\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think last `draw` command can use `--` instead of `-|`. Initial and final coordinates are already vertically aligned.

Comment: You are right, I correct.

Comment: can you change your solution using the same line used by a `\umluniassoc`?

Comment: @AntonioSantoro Antonio, if you look at [tikz-uml documentation, page 15](https://perso.ensta-paris.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/var/files/doc/tikzumlmanual.pdf), will see that you can use `angle` anchor to start or end associations, but in your case as classes have different size, angular anchors are not equivalent and it's difficult to get a vertical union. You have to use AndréC solution, resize both nodes to make it equal and use angular anchors or use a `|-` join between east anchor on upper node and north anchor in Relay.

Comment: @AntonioSantoro I discover the `tikz-uml` package with your question, I went through its manual and your case is not taken into account. Why do you need the macro `umluniassoc` to draw this arrow vertically ?

Comment: @Ignasi using `geometry=|-` will cause the second arm to be sticked to the rectangle through the anchor north

Comment: @AndréC I only need the same arrow style

Comment: @AntonioSantoro The arrow you want to obtain is this one. `Straight Barb[length=4pt,width=3.4pt]` You can change its width and length in case I did not put it at the exact dimensions. I have updated the answer.